# Installing darknet on Windows 10

Tags: c++, opencv, yolo, darknet, vcpkg

I'm trying to install darknet on Windows 10 using the instructions in the following link:
https://github.com/kiyoshiiriemon/yolov4_darknet/tree/b504cc3b4e47617c2cf28c37a6581fc733854f06

However, I got the following error through Windows PowerShell:

```
-- Configuring x64-windows CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:106 (message):
    Command failed: ninja -v
    Working Directory: C:/Users/hedey/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/x64-windows-rel/vcpkg-parallel-configure
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\hedey\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\config-x64-windows-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):   scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_cmake.cmake:312 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)   ports/opencv4/portfile.cmake:280 (vcpkg_configure_cmake)   scripts/ports.cmake:135 (include)
Error: Building package opencv4:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:   Package: opencv4:x64-windows   Vcpkg version:
2020.06.15-nohash
Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.
```

I'm totally stuck getting a solution for this issue.

This is the complete log file can be found in the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f30g354t26n1mvg/log_files.zip?dl=0

I noticed that the png.h file exists at C:\Users\hedey\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\libpng16 instead of C:\Users\hedey\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\libpng (which is where it's being searched for as in the CMakeError file.
Also, both of png.h and pthread.h exist at C:\Users\hedey\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include.

**EDIT:**
The above problem was solved after I updated vcpkg (using git pull).
However, I got another error as follows:

```
FAILED: modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj 
cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\hedey\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\x64-windows-dbg\modules\core\CMakeFiles\cuda_compile_1.dir\src\cuda && C:\Users\hedey\vcpkg\downloads\tools\cmake-3.18.4-windows\cmake-3.18.4-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E make_directory C:/Users/hedey/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/x64-windows-dbg/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/. && C:\Users\hedey\vcpkg\downloads\tools\cmake-3.18.4-windows\cmake-3.18.4-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -D verbose:BOOL=OFF -D build_configuration:STRING=Debug -D generated_file:STRING=C:/Users/hedey/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/x64-windows-dbg/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj -D generated_cubin_file:STRING=C:/Users/hedey/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/x64-windows-dbg/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj.cubin.txt -P C:/Users/hedey/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/x64-windows-dbg/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj.Debug.cmake"
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj.Debug.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  C:/Users/hedey/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/x64-windows-dbg/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj
```

I faced this problem before with the cmake gui, and it can be solved by setting CUDA_ARCH_BIN to the value that's suitable to the GPU (6.1 in my case).
However, I don't know how to solve it in case of installing using vcpkg. I tried to find a file where I can edit, and I think it's 'OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake'. I tried some edits to that file, and I'm still getting the same error. Could you pls help me overcome this issue?